# Reducibility over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathbf{F}_q$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$.

Can one characterize all polynomials $f(X) \in \mathbf{F}_q[X]$ such that $f(X)^p - X$ is reducible?

(Obviously this is the case if $X$ divides $f(X)$. But what other cases are there?)

Comment: Certainly, if $f(X)^p-X$ is irreducible in $F_q$, then in $F_{q^{pn}}\cong F_q[X]/\langle f(X)^p-X\rangle$ it splits, where $n$ is the degree of $f$.